# ¿Cómo salto una variable?

Tags: java

Quiero dividir el mayor número y menor número de una lista de 10 números, pero la cosa es que quiero que cuando menor número sea 0, se salte al menor valor más cercano: o sea, si en la lista está *2 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 20*, no se divida *20/0* sino *20/2*.
Esto lo que yo hice hasta ahora:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Main.java to edit this template
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Franklyn
 */
public class Vector06 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        // DECLARACION DE VARIABLES
        int N, c,teta;
        int NUM[] = new int[10]; // SE DECLARA y SE CREA EL ARREGLO
        int menor,mayor;
        float divi;
        // INGRESO DE DATOS, SE CAPTURAN COMO String (TEXTO) 
        for ( int I= 0; I <= NUM.length-1; I++)
        {
            c=I+1;
            String sN=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese " + c +"°"+ " Numero Entero:");
            // CONVERTIR LOS DATOS INGRESADOS A NUMEROS
            N=Integer.parseInt(sN);
            NUM[I]=N;

        }
        // determinando el menor valOR
        menor=NUM[0];// se le asigna cualquier valor del vector
        for(int I=0;I<=9;I++)
        {
            if(NUM[I]<menor)
                menor=NUM[I];
        }
        // determinando el mayor valor
        mayor=NUM[0];// se le asigna cualquier valor del vector
        for(int I=0;I<=9;I++)
            if(NUM[I]>mayor)
                   mayor=NUM[I]; 
        //Division de numeros
        divi=(float)(mayor)/menor;
  
        //Cambiar el 0
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La division del mayor entre el menor numero es "+divi);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución, trata en que cuando estás buscando el número mas pequeño, te asegures de que el número no es cero. En caso de que sea cero, no lo va a guardar en tu variable `menor`

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class pruebaSO {
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt
 * to change this license Click
 * nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Main.java to edit this
 * template
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Franklyn
 */

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    // DECLARACION DE VARIABLES
    int N, c, teta;
    int NUM[] = new int[10]; // SE DECLARA y SE CREA EL ARREGLO
    int menor, mayor;
    float divi;
    // INGRESO DE DATOS, SE CAPTURAN COMO String (TEXTO)
    for (int I = 0; I <= NUM.length - 1; I++) {
        c = I + 1;
        String sN = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese " + c + "°" + " Numero Entero:");
        // CONVERTIR LOS DATOS INGRESADOS A NUMEROS
        N = Integer.parseInt(sN);
        NUM[I] = N;

    }
    // determinando el menor valOR
    menor = NUM[0];// se le asigna cualquier valor del vector
    for (int I = 0; I <= 9; I++) {
        if (NUM[I] < menor && NUM[I] != 0)
            menor = NUM[I];
    }
    // determinando el mayor valor
    mayor = NUM[0];// se le asigna cualquier valor del vector
    for (int I = 0; I <= 9; I++)
        if (NUM[I] > mayor)
            mayor = NUM[I];
    // Division de numeros
    divi = (float) (mayor) / menor;

    // Cambiar el 0
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La division del mayor entre el menor numero es " + divi);
}
```

}